# Docker: git operations not permitted in dir which is mounted from Win10's to container running ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, git, docker, permissions

Company's PC is Win10 and can't bring self's LP, and I want to develop in Linux, So I'm preparing to install a docker on Windows and run a Linux container on whcih I perform my development.

---  **background** ---

I've installed a `Docker Desktop for Windows`(19.03.8) in Win10 and pull a Ubuntu image.
I start the Ubuntu container with `-v` to mount my win10's `host_dir` to container's `slave_dir`.
The `host_dir` before mount has already been a git repo with a `.git` directory in `host_dir`.
Through ssh with `root user`, I edit the file in `slave_dir` in container and when I want to commit the changes, the following error appears:

```sh
root@5f8d7d02ee70:~/slave_dir# git status
fatal: failed to read object 36fa53e7ecb9d1daa454fc82f7bd7310afa335b7: Operation not permitted
```

I guess something is wrong with the git `Authority` between Win10 and my Linux-container

Linux-container's slave_dir:
[image]

Win10's host_dir:
[image]

And I've got a similar circumstance, in which the blogger said **You should run the docker with --user**, and **the `--user`'s param should be the same with you login on the host**

So I tried as follows:

```sh
docker run -it --name test --user Leo -p 127.0.0.1:5001 -v host_dir:slave_dir image_name /bin/bash
```

Unfortunately, the slave_dir's `uid` and `gid` are still `root`.

With cygwin on Win10, I use `id` to find my login user's uid and gid,
and retry run docker with uid/gid directly.

```sh
docker run -it --name test --user 4344296:1049089 -p 127.0.0.1:5001 -v host_dir:slave_dir image_name /bin/bash
```

[image]

OMG, still not work! Still root! ... ...
I'm wondering whether my operation is wrong or window's Docker-Desktop-For-Windows has some tricks with Authority when mounting.
Thanks all!

Comment: I'm going to guess that this has to do with that some operations you can do on files in linux have not been mapped to equivalent windows operations by the docker engine. It's then not a permission problem, it's a capability problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a problem with Docker 2.2.0.4. A fix to this problem can be found at this [link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6016) (It worked for me).

**TL;DR:** Remove the read-only permission from .git folder in windows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.I check the directory's property and it is `read-only`. I download the bugfix version from [here](https://download-stage.docker.com/win/stable/43542/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe) and re-install the docker-desktop-for-windows, the git can work.  Just the `read-only` problem.